# Select one column header same name and display data horizontal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables :

1-contracts

```
    contracts_id  |  subject_contract  
    001           |  name              
    002           |  name
```

2-contracts_files

```
    contracts_id  |  file_data
    001           |  1image <varbinary(MAX)>
    002           |  1image <varbinary(MAX)>
    001           |  2image <varbinary(MAX)>
    002           |  2image <varbinary(MAX)>
```

Need SQL output like this result :

```
contracts_id  |  subject_contract  |  file_data   |  file_data 
001           |  name              |  1image      |  2image 
002           |  name              |  1image      |  2image
```

I try this

```
SELECT Contracts.[contracts_id]  
      ,Contracts.[subject_contract]
      ,contracts_files.[filedata]


  FROM Contracts , contracts_files

  where contracts_files.contracts_id = Contracts.contracts_id

  AND Contracts.contracts_id=' 001 '
```

but the result was :

```
contracts_id  |  subject_contract  |  file_data  
    001       |  name              |  1image  
    001       |  name              |  2image
```

So how can i create it with 'FOR LOOP' or with 'CASE' ?

Comment: So, you ask for a solution using CASE, and then accept an answer that doesn't use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pivot as below:

```
Select * from (
    SELECT c.[contracts_id]  
          ,c.[subject_contract]
          ,cf.[filedata]
          ,RN = Row_Number() over (partition by c.[Contracts_id] order by c.[contracts_id])
      FROM Contracts c join contracts_files cf
      ON cf.contracts_id = c.contracts_id
      ) a
      pivot (max(filedata) for RN in ([1],[2]) ) p
```

Comment: thanks for reply : but something wrong in ' pivot (max(filedata) for RN in ([1],[2]) ) p '

Comment: I think it is expecting alias... i updated, can you check now, whats error?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like pivot, do the old way of case (when some variable = 1) then (some value). If the when doesn't work out, null is used, the MAX() will not return a null. Highlight the inner query and run just that to see how the data looks half way thru the transform if you're curious

```
SELECT
  contracts_id,
  subject_contract,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rown = 1 then file_data end) as file1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rown = 2 then file_data end) as file2

FROM 
  (SELECT c.contracts_id, subject_contract, file_data, row_number() over (partition by c.[Contracts_id] order by c.[contracts_id]) as rown FROM contracts c INNER JOIN contracts_files cf ON cf.contracts_id = c.contracts_id) a
GROUP BY
  contracts_id, 
  subject_contract
```